# How to cancel Client.send in Tdlib?

Tags: java, android, telegram, tdlib

I'm writing Telegram authentication via Tdlib and have found that library handles retries internally (e.g. when I'm trying to send phone number to start authentication and connection is poor/missing library would schedule pause-n-retry internally).

The problem is that I can't stop it or at least change retry policy. Neither I was able to send the same request again if it was scheduled for retry.

Any ideas how to get over this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So apparently the answer is to send `TdApi.ResendAuthenticationCode`. Other available resend actions are:

- `TdApi.ResendChangePhoneNumberCode`
- `TdApi.ResendEmailAddressVerificationCode`
- `TdApi.ResendMessages`
- `TdApi.ResendPhoneNumberConfirmationCode`
- `TdApi.ResendPhoneNumberVerificationCode`
- `TdApi.ResendRecoveryEmailAddressCode`